# Foreign characters showing from gcc compiler output

Tags: raspi-config, gcc, locale

My locales are are set to generate `en_US.ISO-8859-15 ISO-8859-15` and `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8`.  However the borders of raspi-config still have borders showing the accented `âââ`.  And the `gcc` compiler output also show messages surround by this same character, for example:

```
test.c:9:22: error: âaddrâ undeclared
```

I am accessing my Pi remotely via SSH using Putty. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in Putty not the Pi. To fix the problem:

1. Load the stored profile for the Pi (I assume you have saved you connection details).
2. Open **Putty Configuration**.
3. From the left side menu **click Translation** from the **Window** section.
4. In the **Remote character set** dropdown select UTF-8.
5. Make sure that **Use Unicode line drawing code points** is selected.
6. Save the stored config and restart putty.

You should no longer see the accented characters.